# Chart.js- Line Chart small value and big value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a line chart with two data sets, The data set with larger numbers makes the other line look flat. How can I fix this issue of it looking flat?

[image: Count looks flat compared to the total dataset]

Comment: Give it a second y-axis with a different scale. Or apply a logarithmic scale for the axis you have instead of a linear one. http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/logarithmic.html?h=logarithmic and http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/?h=creating%20multiple%20axes

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem.

Comment: @John I know its a long time but can you post your solution as an answer?